# Find and replace inside a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel file I have:

```
    A     
1 10-30       
2 40-45      
3 30-80
```

There can be any range of numbers separated by `-` in any cell.

In any particular column (might be any cell) i want to remove all text from the start to the `-` hyphen.

Example: *40-45* will be replaced with *45*.

Comment: do you want to replace the content of the cell with the value that appears after the `-` *dash* sign ? So you `A1 = 30`, `A2 = 45`, `A3 = 80`?

Comment: Simply use text to column. No need for VBA here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will iterate through all worksheets and their used ranges ( all cells in all sheets in one workbook ) and replace any text that is separated by a `-` *dash*  i.e `40-50` with only the second part of the string (50)

```
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, r As Range
    For Each ws In Sheets
        Set ur = ws.UsedRange
        For Each r In ur
            On Error Resume Next
                r = Split(r, "-")(1)
        Next
    Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You could also use the below

```
Sub MMain()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, r As Range
    For Each ws In Sheets
        Set ur = ws.UsedRange
        For Each r In ur
            If Not IsEmpty(r) Then
                If InStr(1, r.Text, "-", vbTextCompare) Then
                    r = Split(r, "-")(1)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

but in this particular case using the first example is about 50% faster then the second one.

I have tested it with 100,000 cells to check and split

Result for the first one:  `2.31 sec`
Result for the second one: `4.62 sec`

Comment: Hi, All the worksheets are getting updated..
I want only one worksheet that to particular coloum to be updated..
Please help me out in this

Comment: @user2818464 please consider asking a new question as your original question should now be solved. Post the code and ask how to limit it to iterate only one worksheet and one specific column. Editing your original question would invalidate the existing answers so try to avoid that if possible :)

Comment: ohh.. Actually i'm new to stackoverflow
I'll ask it again.. Once again thanks for your answer

Comment: no worries and welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use a regular expression to be selective on the replacement

This code will prompt you for a range to operate on.

```
Sub Update()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rngArea As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim lngCalc As Long
Dim objReg As Object
Dim X()

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select range for the replacement of leading zeros", "User select", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0


Set objReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objReg.Pattern = "\d+\-(\d+)"

'Speed up the code by turning off screenupdating and setting calculation to manual
'Disable any code events that may occur when writing to cells
With Application
    lngCalc = .Calculation
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With


'Non contiguous range areas are common when using SpecialCells to define specific cell types to work on
For Each rngArea In rng1.Areas
    'The most common outcome is used for the True outcome to optimise code speed
    If rngArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
       'If there is more than once cell then set the variant array to the dimensions of the range area
       'Using Value2 provides a useful speed improvement over Value. On my testing it was 2% on blank cells, up to 10% on non-blanks
        X = rngArea.Value2
        For lngRow = 1 To rngArea.Rows.Count
            For lngCol = 1 To rngArea.Columns.Count
                'replace text
                X(lngRow, lngCol) = objReg.Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), "$1")
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        'Dump the updated array sans leading whitepace back over the initial range
        rngArea.Value2 = X
    Else
        'caters for a single cell range area. No variant array required
        rngArea.Value = objReg.Replace(rngArea.Value, "$1")
    End If
Next rngArea

'cleanup the Application settings
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = lngCalc
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

Set objReg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for regex but from my experience working with `.Replace` is quite slow if youre working with lots of cells

Comment: Not inside a variant array :)